# Accessing swarm-master via api

Tags: docker, postman, docker-swarm

I installed a swarm cluster in vagrant and I'm trying to control swarm-master via rest call from post man. I think we need to configure something in "DOCKER_OPTS" inside /etc/init/docker.conf . Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: Make sure you use the documentation for "swarm mode" which is part of the `engine api`. https://docs.docker.com/swarm/swarm-api/

Comment: Thanks for the response i'm aware of this api , my problem is im trying to get the details of the container for example : GET "<IP-of-swarm-master>/containers/json" i ve to configure the ip address rt ?? . i am not aware of that configuration

Comment: That doc is about swarm classic, not the new swarm mode components of the engine api.

Answer (score 0):

i am answering my own question

add this `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://IPaddress:portnumber`

in the environment file `nano /etc/environment`